# SBT: Updating Project References

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

in Build.scala, you can specify that a library dependency should be updated each time by using the changing method. For example:

```
"com.github.seratch" %% "scalikesolr" % "4.6.0" changing()
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing for project references to external URI. For example:

```
RootProject(uri("git://git@github.com/Somewhere/project.git"))
```

Updates don't seem to trigger the project reference to update.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with sbt, see: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1120